# To address a stranger on street

Tags: phrases, american-english

Preparing for our honeymoon in the USA, I am wondering what is the most appropriate way to address someone (a stranger) on street, e.g. to ask for a piece of advice. I can imagine that

> Good day sir! Would you mind helping me out?

is a too formal way. Or is the most common way

> Excuse me sir, can you spare a minute?

Furthermore, how do I address a female stranger? Dependent on the strangers age, is

> Ma'am

an option?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This might better be addressed on [Travel.SE](http://travel.stackexchange.com/). But as an American, my advice would be to get to the point quickly, especially in cities; the culture does not value the pre-request banter that is required in some parts of the world, which will annoy or come off as a sales or panhandling pitch. The greeting and sir/maam is superfluous. *Excuse me, does this train stop at Addison?* *Pardon me, do you know if there's a gas station nearby?* *Hello, sorry, but do you have change for a twenty?*

Answer (score 2):

Slather us Americans with your British accent and we won't care what you say--we'll bend over backwards trying to help you regardless of how you address us.

> "Tally ho, good chap! I say, where mightst one get a spot of tea with some
>   buscuits?"

The key to getting help from strangers won't be to assimilate but to sound as British as can be.  As for addressing the ladies, with that accent, how you'll be addressing them is in the morning as you roll over, " 'Ello, luv!"

Comment: hahahaha! I like it.. Overloaded with stereotypes but I like it. How do you know OP is British?

Comment: @BuscuitBoy : Hi, BB.  I can hear it in the syntax.  It is positively dripping with Britishness, innit?

Comment: What an enjoyable gag. I attest you a sense of humoUr: :)
English is not my mother tongue, but I am from Europe, so what I learned in school is BE. Don't stone me for that. :D

Comment: Thank you, thank you!  Hold you're applause!  I'll be here all week!

Comment: @Benjamin such stereotypically British, but dated, phrasing suggests (to these British ears) a speaker more used to Indian English.

Comment: @Chris H : Yes, 'twas intentionally over the top.  What, what?  I daresay.  Yo ho ho and a bottle of rum!  Easy peasy lemon squeezy.  Blimey, it's bigger on the inside.  EXTERMINATE!  We are NOT amused!